# Access a variable in another view controller - Xcode 8.0 Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

How do I set a variable on one VC and then access it on another VC? I know that you need to use prepare for segue but I want to access the variable when the VC appears. This is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("viewDidAppear")

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        print("prepare for segue")

        let variableUnwind = ("StackOverFlow")

        if segue.identifier == "toFirstViewController"  {

            let hello = segue.destination as! AddItemViewController

            print(hello.username)



        }

    }

}
```

I know that prepare for segue means that the actions in that function will happen before a segue but I don't know how to eliminate prepare for segue without losing what will happen in that function.

Basically, I want to set a variable on VC2 and the access it on VC1 when VC1 has loaded. If It helps I am using an unwind segue to go to VC1 from VC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

hello.whatever your variable name is = the new variable you created on VC2

after you declare the hello variable

hope this helps

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
print("viewDidAppear")

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    print("prepare for segue")

    let variableUnwind = ("StackOverFlow")

    if segue.identifier == "toFirstViewController"  {

        let hello = segue.destination as! AddItemViewController
```

*hello.variableName = newVariableName*

```
    }

}
```

}